# SUM time values where column to the right has specific string value

Tags: google-sheets

In my specific example I have a time sheet, and for each project I will just add a tag next to the time spend. Like "Project1" or "Project2". What I want to archieve is to show a SUM of the time spend on this project and show it on a sheet with project name and total time spend. Is this possible?

See attached image for example.

[image: Example picture]

I want the calculation to show in cells `G2` and `G3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works (for the example you showed us above)

```
=ArrayFormula(query({value(B3:B), C3:C}, "select Col2, sum(Col1) where Col2 <>'' group by Col2 label sum(Col1) '' format sum(Col1) 'hh:mm'"))
```

Note: format the second column of the output as duration (via the 123-menu).

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This did the job!

Answer (score 0):

Please try in G2 and copied down to suit (with formatting as Duration):

```
=sumif(C:C,F2,B:B)
```